# Powershell Version 2 compared to version 4 loading dlls

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works perfectly in powershell version 4 but when I move it onto a machine with version 2 it kicks up a fuss.
My code is below I have a controller which loads the scripts like so

```
$ScriptDir=Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
try {


    . ("$ScriptDir\Migration1file.ps1")
    # ("$ScriptDir\DryRunforCopyMigration.ps1")


}
catch {
    Write-Host "An error happened when loading supporting PowerShell Scripts" 
}
```

I then load the below script by `Copy-Files username site folder doclubname
And then the actual script itself:

```
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}

Function UploadFile($DestinationFolder, $File, $FileSource)
{


    if($FileSource -eq $null){
        $FileSource = $Folder
    }
    $path= [String]$FileSource+'\'+$File
            $Size = get-item $Path
        $Size = $Size.length

    if($Size -lt 160000){
    if($path -like '*.doc*' -Or $path -like '*.xls*' -Or $path -like '*.ppt*'){
    ##Get authors of document
    if($path -like '*.doc*'){
    $application = New-Object -ComObject word.application
    $application.Visible = $false
    $document = $application.documents.open($path)
    }
    if($path -like '*.xls*'){
    $application = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
    $application.Visible = $false
    $document = $application.workbooks.open($path)
    }   
    if($path -like '*.ppt*'){
    $application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
    $application.Visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
    $document = $application.presentations.open($path)
    }   


    $binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
    $properties = $document.BuiltInDocumentProperties
    foreach($property in $properties)
    {
        $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("name",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)

        trap [system.exception]
        {

            continue
        }
        if ($pn -eq "Last author") {
            $lastSaved = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
            $lastSaved = [String]$lastSaved


        }
        if ($pn -eq "author") {
            $author = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
            $author = [String]$author
        }

    }

    $document.Close()
    $application.quit()
    if($path -like '*.ppt*'){
    $application = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Stop-Process –name powerpnt 
}
    ##set author if null returned
    if($lastSaved -eq ''){
    $lastSaved = "Rob Ireland"
    }
    if($author -eq ''){
    $author = "Rob Ireland"
    }

    $author =$Context.Web.EnsureUser($author)
    $lastSaved = $Context.Web.EnsureUser($lastSaved)
    }else{

    $CreationOwner =Get-Acl $path | Select-Object Owner
    write-host "Uploaded with out modified by and created by metadata"

    #$lastSaved = "Rob Ireland"


    #$author = "Rob Ireland"

    }
    ##Get created date
    $CreationDate = Get-ItemProperty -Path $FileSource\$File | Select-Object CreationTime
    $CreateDT =  [string]$CreationDate.CreationTime
    $revDate,$Time = $CreateDT.Split(" ",2)
    $arr = $revDate -split '/'
    $revDate = $arr[2]+'-'+$arr[0]+'-'+$arr[1]
    $DateSP = $revDate+'T'+$Time

    ##Get Modified date
    $ModifiedDate = Get-ItemProperty -Path $FileSource\$File | Select-Object LastWriteTime
    $ModDT =  [string]$ModifiedDate.LastWriteTime
    $ModDate,$ModTime = $ModDT.Split(" ",2)
    $Modarr = $ModDate -split '/'   
    $ModDate = $Modarr[2]+'-'+$Modarr[0]+'-'+$Modarr[1] 
    $ModDateSP = $ModDate+'T'+$ModTime



    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
    $Upload = $DestinationFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $ListItem = $Upload.ListItemAllFields;

    $Listitem["Modified"] = $ModDateSP

    $Listitem["Created"] = $DateSP
    $Listitem["Author"] = $author  
    $Listitem["Editor"] = $lastSaved  

    $ListItem.Update()
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    }else{
    write-host "File TOOO BIG"
    }
}

function PopulateFolder($ListRootFolder, $FolderRelativePath)
{

    #split the FolderRelativePath passed into chunks (between the backslashes) so that we can check if the folder structure exists
    $PathChunks = $FolderRelativePath.substring(1).split("\")

    #Make sure we start with a fresh WorkingFolder for every folder passed to the function
    if($WorkingFolder)
    {
        Remove-Variable WorkingFolder
    }

    #Start with the root folder of the list, load this into context
    $WorkingFolder = $ListRootFolder
    $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Load the folders of the current working folder into context
    $Context.load(($WorkingFolder.folders))
    $Context.executeQuery()

    #Set the FileSource folder equal to the absolute path of the folder that passed to the function
    $FileSource = $Folder + $FolderRelativePath

    #Loop through the folder chunks, ensuring that the correct folder hierarchy exists in the destination
    foreach($Chunk in $PathChunks)
    {
        #Check to find out if a subfolder exists in the current folder that matches the patch chunk being evaluated
        if($WorkingFolder.folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Chunk})
        {
            #Log the status to the PowerShell host window
            Write-Host "Folder $Chunk Exists in" $WorkingFolder.name -ForegroundColor Green

            #Since we will be evaluating other chunks in the path, set the working folder to the current folder and load this into context.
            $WorkingFolder = $WorkingFolder.folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Chunk}
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder.folders)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        }
        else
        {
            #If the folder doesn't exist, Log a message indicating that the folder doesn't exist, and another message indicating that it is being created
            Write-Host "Folder $Chunk Does Not Exist in" $WorkingFolder.name -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host "Creating Folder $Chunk in" $WorkingFolder.name -ForegroundColor Green

            #Load the working folder into context and create a subfolder with a name equal to the chunk being evaluated, and load this into context
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder.folders)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()
            $WorkingFolder= $WorkingFolder.folders.add($Chunk)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder)
            $Context.load($WorkingFolder.folders)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()


        }

    }

    #Folder is confirmed existing or created - now it's time to list all files in the source folder, and assign this to a variable
    $FilesInFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource | ? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $False}

    #For each file in the source folder being evaluated, call the UploadFile function to upload the file to the appropriate location
    Foreach ($File in ($FilesInFolder))
    {

        #Notify the operator that the file is being uploaed to a specific location
        Write-Host "Uploading file " $file.Name "to" $WorkingFolder.name -ForegroundColor Cyan
        if(!($File -like '*.txt')){
        try{
        #Upload the file
        UploadFile $WorkingFolder $File $FileSource
        }catch{
                Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Host "No further parts of the migration will be completed, The script will now exit" 
                Exit
        }
        }else{
            Write-Host "Not copied across to sharepoint"
        }

    }



}


Function Copy-Files{

    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Folder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$DocLibName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials

    )


    try{
        #Bind to site collection
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)


                $pass =  ConvertTo-SecureString $credentials.Password -AsPlainText -Force

                $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials.UserName,$pass)
        $Context.Credentials = $Creds
    #Retrieve list
    $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
    $Context.Load($List)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()


    #Get a recursive list of all folders beneath the folder supplied by the operator
    $AllFolders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Folder |? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $True}

    #Get a list of all files that exist directly at the root of the folder supplied by the operator
    $FilesInRoot = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder | ? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $False}
    }catch{                          
                Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Host "No further parts of the migration will be completed, The script will now exit" 
                Exit
        }

    #Upload all files in the root of the folder supplied by the operator
    Foreach ($File in ($FilesInRoot))
    {

        #Notify the operator that the file is being uploaded to a specific location
        Write-Host "Uploading file " $File.Name "to" $DocLibName -ForegroundColor Cyan

        if(!($File -like '*.txt')){
        #Upload the file
        try{
        UploadFile($list.RootFolder) $File
        }catch{
                Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Host "No further parts of the migration will be completed, The script will now exit" 
                Exit
        }
        }else{
            Write-Host "Not copied across to sharepoint"
        }



    }

    #Loop through all folders (recursive) that exist within the folder supplied by the operator
    foreach($CurrentFolder in $AllFolders)
    {
        try{
        #Set the FolderRelativePath by removing the path of the folder supplied by the operator from the fullname of the folder
        $FolderRelativePath = ($CurrentFolder.FullName).Substring($Folder.Length)

        #Call the PopulateFolder function for the current folder, which will ensure that the folder exists and upload all files in the folder to the appropriate location
        PopulateFolder ($list.RootFolder) $FolderRelativePath
        }catch{
                        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
                Write-Host "No further parts of the migration will be completed, The script will now exit" 
                Exit

        }


    }





}
```

I get an error saying loading supporting powershell scripts and I believe its something to do with loading in the dlls

Comment: Add-Type is available in PS 2 but is your path correct? I assume you are doing this because it is SP 2010? In that case 15 should be 14.

Comment: the path is correct

Comment: In that case you need to give more context. Why are you using PS 2? What is the exception? line number etc.